# Naïve Bayes Algorithm Always comes out as 0

Tags: artificial-intelligence, classification, probability, text-classification, naivebayes

I have a question regarding the Naïve Bayes classification method.
I ran though what I thought was an easy example but ran into a snag.

Basically here is the classification I would like to do:

I want to be able to take some training data:

```
input1 | input2 |  input3 | class
  1        3         3        1
  2        1         1        2
  1        1         1        3
  3        3         3        1
```

and classify them into a class 1-3.

As I understand it first you compute the prior probability of
the class so in this case that would be

```
class 1 = P(c_1) = 0.50
class 2 = P(c_2) = 0.25
class 3 = P(c_3) = 0.25
```

which thusfar makes perfect sense.  They all add to 1 and its
very easy to see where those numbers come from.

So due to the numerical nature of those values I wanted to simplify
them into ranges.  So I reconstructed my data into this:

So anyways that how I got to that table.  Continuing with the Bayes part:

```
P(Class 1 | avg_speed_1): 0.5
P(Class 1 | avg_speed_2): 0
P(Class 1 | avg_speed_3): 0
P(Class 2 | avg_speed_1): 0
P(Class 2 | avg_speed_2): 0.25
P(Class 2 | avg_speed_3): 0
P(Class 3 | avg_speed_1): 0
P(Class 3 | avg_speed_2): 0
P(Class 3 | avg_speed_3): 0.25
P(Class 1 | avg_distance_1): 0.5
P(Class 1 | avg_distance_2): 0
P(Class 1 | avg_distance_3): 0
P(Class 2 | avg_distance_1): 0
P(Class 2 | avg_distance_2): 0.25
P(Class 2 | avg_distance_3): 0
P(Class 3 | avg_distance_1): 0
P(Class 3 | avg_distance_2): 0
P(Class 3 | avg_distance_3): 0.25
P(Class 1 | avg_elev_gain_1): 0.5
P(Class 1 | avg_elev_gain_2): 0
P(Class 1 | avg_elev_gain_3): 0
P(Class 2 | avg_elev_gain_1): 0
P(Class 2 | avg_elev_gain_2): 0
P(Class 2 | avg_elev_gain_3): 0
P(Class 3 | avg_elev_gain_1): 0
P(Class 3 | avg_elev_gain_2): 0
P(Class 3 | avg_elev_gain_3): 0.5
```

now this all still makes sense to me.  each class still adds to 1 however
when I go to compute the probability for each class, the 0's screw up the calculation

take the first class for example:

```
P(Class 1 | avg_speed_1) *
P(Class 1 | avg_speed_2) *
P(Class 1 | avg_speed_3) *
P(Class 1 | avg_distance_1) *
P(Class 1 | avg_distance_2) *
P(Class 1 | avg_distance_3) *
P(Class 1 | avg_elev_gain_1) *
P(Class 1 | avg_elev_gain_2) *
P(Class 1 | avg_elev_gain_3) *
P(Class 1) = 0
```

I've found that this always equals zero because there are a number of
input elements that still zero!  Where did I go wrong?!? Does this mean that I have insufficient training data?

That being said is the Naïve Bayes approach even the right way to approach this classification?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why are you *multiplying* the conditional probabilities together like that? Of course when you multiply a set of numbers which contains 0 you get a 0 product -- but the product that you are computing seems pointless to compute. You seem to be misremembering the law of total probability. Also -- note that "naïve" isn't spelled "nieve".

Comment: Exactly.  Thats where I know something is going wrong.  in the formula I saw that it was the product of P(C | i1) * P(C| i2) * P(C| i3) * P(C) that gives the answer.  Which seems very wrong because if any one of those probabilities is 0, then the entire probability will be 0.  @JohnColeman once the prior probabilities have been computed,  how would you then make a prediction of the class such as given inputs i1,i2,i3 if it is not the product of all the conditional probabilities

Comment: The formula in the Wikipedia article on Naïve Bayes Classifier seems to suggest that all of the conditional probabilities you have are backwards. You should be multiplying the things like `P(avg_speed_1|Class 1)` rather than `P(avg_speed_1|Class 1)`.